# Apach2.2 Curl working, not Netcat

Tags: curl, netcat, apache2.2

I'm trying to install mod_status on my server. I'm using Apache 2.2 and I use this configuration :

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
    Listen 8001
    ExtendedStatus On
    <VirtualHost *:8001>
        <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost ip6-localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I use `curl`, I have the correct output :
`curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/server-status?auto`

```
Total Accesses: 4519
Total kBytes: 128320
CPULoad: 10.6216
Uptime: 962
[...]
```

When I use netcat, it fails (no output) :

```
echo 'GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1' | nc localhost 8001
echo -e "GET /server-status?auto\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
echo -e "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
echo -e "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
echo -e "GET http://localhost:8001/server-status?auto HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
echo -e "GET http://localhost:8001/server-status?auto\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
echo "GET http://localhost:8001/server-status?auto" | nc localhost 8001
printf "GET http://localhost:8001/server-status?auto\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
printf "GET /server-status?auto\r\n" | nc localhost 8001
echo -ne "GET /server-status?auto\r\n\r\n" |nc localhost 8001
echo -ne "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" |nc localhost 8001
echo -ne "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1\r\n" |nc localhost 8001
printf "GET /server-status?auto\r\n"
printf "GET /server-status?auto\n"|nc localhost 8001
echo -ne "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: netcat\r\nHost: localhost:8001\r\nAccept: */*\r\n" | netcat 127.0.0.1 8001
echo -ne "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15\r\nHost: localhost:8001\r\nAccept: */*\r\n" | netcat 127.0.0.1 8001
```

But, when I do `nc 127.0.0.1 8001` and type `GET /server-status?auto` + enter in the prompt, it works ...

What is wrong ?

Thanks you,
G.

Answer (score 1):

I think netcat quit before getting a response, when I use -q1 it works : `echo "GET /server-status" | nc -q1 127.0.0.1 8001`

`man nc` :
`-q` after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.`